# trying to get a single string out of a line in perl

Tags: perl

I am running a pgrep command and trying to get a string from the output of pgrep command.
    `pgrep -fl bipbroker` (this is the process name) gives the output 
    (This is the output of the pgrep command): `15334 bipbroker Broker1`.
I want to get just `Broker1` printed from this output. I am using split but it doesn't seem to work.

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $Broker;
open my $command_output, "|-", "pgrep -fl bipbroker";
while (my $command = < $command_output > ) {
    $Broker= split(/' '/, $command, [ -1]);
    print $Broker;
}
```

Comment: Do you really need the quotes in your regex? It doesn't match what you give as the output from pgrep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using `split` incorrectly.

You want to take the last element of the split.

In two lines you could do it like this:

```
@split_line = split /\s+/, $command;
$Broker = $split_line[-1];
```

In one line you'd do it like this:

```
$Broker = (split /\s+/, $command)[-1];
```

Moreover, as [mpapec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/223226/mpapec) [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20072019/1084), you appear to be opening your pipe incorrectly.

You wrote:

```
open my $command_output, "|-", "pgrep -fl bipbroker";
```

Which pipes anything you write to `<$command_output>` to `pgrep -fl bipbroker`.  You want do to the opposite.  You want to pipe the `pgrep` to a pipe that you can read, like this:

```
open my $command_output, "pgrep -fl bipbroker|";
```

Comment: I am getting a GLOB message when i run the code with the changes you mentioned.

Comment: This is my code now
`#!/usr/bin/perl`
`use strict;`
`use warnings;`
`my $Broker;`
`open my $command_output, "pgrep -fl bipbroker|";`
`while ( my $command = < $command_output > ) {`
`$Broker = (split /\s+/, $command)[-1];`
`print $Broker;`
`}`
But i get a GLOB message.

Comment: @user2689092: what is the exact message you get?

Comment: It just says GLOB(0x1d6642a0)

Comment: That's because `< $command_output >` is not a `readline()` call, it is a file glob, equivalent to `glob($command_output)`. The file handle gets stringified to `GLOB(...)`, which fails to match any files, and is then assigned to `$command`. You then try and fail to split that string `"GLOB(...)`, and then print it. What you want is `<$command_output>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read from your command then,

```
open my $command_output, "-|", "pgrep -fl bipbroker";
```

instead of,

```
open my $command_output, "|-", "pgrep -fl bipbroker";
```

Answer (score 0):

edit: I just tested the script as a whole as i was unsure about the whole open thing. And it turns out, that does not work at all, you do not get actual strings. It is probably possible to do it that way but i am not too familiar with the many uses of <> so i would suggest not diving too deep and just use:

```
my $Broker;
my @command_output = `pgrep -fl bipbroker`;
for my $command (@command_output) 
{ 
    #loop (see below)
}
```

Also, you are calling `split` in scalar context. I suppose that -1 at the end is supposed to give you the last element as it would if used as an index for an array. But `split` has a three argument form and if the last one is negative it just means split as much as possible. As opposed to skipping empty delimeters at the end if using 0 or nothing.

Also `/' '/` is probably not what you want. It is treated as a regex and looks for actual `'`. You should probably just use `/ /` which is a shortcut for "Cut off any whitespaces at the beginning and then split by any amount of whitespaces greater 0".

So you might want to use:

```
@Broker= split(/ /, $command);
print $Broker[-1];
```